# Attribute Error: 'bool' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'

Tags: python, django, rdbms

I am new to django and I have been trying to learn from the past few days. I have added date time and duration fields into my model.
Now when I am trying to add flights using Django admin site I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError at /admin/flights/flight/add/
'bool' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/flights/flight/add/
Django Version: 4.1.3
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'bool' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'
Exception Location: /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py, line 256, in is_aware
Raised during:  django.contrib.admin.options.add_view
Python Executable:  /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10
Python Version: 3.10.8
Python Path:    
['/Users/janardhanareddyms/Documents/airline',
 '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python310.zip',
 '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10',
 '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/janardhanareddyms/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
 '/opt/homebrew/opt/python-tk@3.10/libexec']
Server time:    Sun, 15 Jan 2023 02:53:34 +0000


Error during template rendering
In template /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html, error at line 19



9               {% for field in line %}
10                  <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="fieldBox{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>
11                      {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
12                      {% if field.is_checkbox %}
13                          {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
14                      {% else %}
15                          {{ field.label_tag }}
16                          {% if field.is_readonly %}
17                              <div class="readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
18                          {% else %}
19                              {{ field.field }}
20                          {% endif %}
21                      {% endif %}
22                      {% if field.field.help_text %}
23                          <div class="help"{% if field.field.id_for_label %} id="{{ field.field.id_for_label }}_helptext"{% endif %}>
24                            {{ field.field.help_text|safe }}
25                          </div>
26                      {% endif %}
27                  </div>
28              {% endfor %}
29          </div>
```

These are my views:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request,"flights/index.html",{
        "flights": Flight.objects.all()
    })

def flight(request, flight_id):
    flight = Flight.objects.get(pk=flight_id)
    return render(request, "flights/flight.html",{
        "flight": flight,
        "passengers": flight.passengers.all(),
        "non_passengers": Passenger.objects.exclude(flights = flight).all()
    })

def book(request,flight_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        flight = Flight.objects.get(pk=flight_id)
        passenger = Passenger.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST["passenger"]))
        passenger.flights.add(flight)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("flights:flight",args=(flight.id,)))
```

and these are my models:

```
class runway(models.Model):
    runways = models.IntegerField()

class Airport(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    airportrunwway = models.ManyToManyField(runway,null=True,blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}:{self.city} ({self.code})'


class Flight(models.Model):
    origin = models.ForeignKey(
        Airport,
        to_field='code',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='departures',
    )
    destination = models.ForeignKey(
        Airport,
        to_field='code',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='arrivals',
    )
    
    duration = models.DurationField(null=True,default=True)
    arrivaltime = models.DateTimeField(null=True,default=True)
    departuretime = models.DateTimeField(null=True,default=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}: {self.origin} to {self.destination}'
```

also I have been trying to create a multivalued for airport model as airportrunway. Can some one also tell if what I have done is correct.
would be thankful I someone answer these for me.

I added date time field for arrival and departure and wanted to add filter option to sort flights by their arrival and departure times. But now I am not able to add flights in django using admin site.

Comment: Why do you pass `default=True` in your models DurationField and DateTimeFields? `True` is not a valid value for those fields

Comment: can I know how to pass a default value as instance of datetime coz the value I enter its considering it as string.